# Why will data not bind if success and error are defined - datatables ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatable

My ajax call is:

```
var networkslisttab = null;
```

...

```
networkslisttab = $('#networkslisttable').DataTable({
    "ajax": { "url": networkstoolboxURL, "dataType": "json", "dataSrc": '', "success": function (data) { networkslisttab.processing(false); console.log(data); }, "error": function (error) { console.log("error in networks"); } },
    //"dataSrc": '',        
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": 'reference_id',
            "width": '15%',
        },
        { "data": 'name' },
        {
            "data": 'num_points',
            "width": '15%',
        },
        {
            "data": 'num_sections',
            "width": '15%',
        }
    ],
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "processing": true,
    "autoWidth": false, // need this to handle rendering issues in bootstrap and during re-size.  Note handlers at end of page.
    "scrollY": "200px",  // make it a small scrolling table
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "language": {
        "processing": '<span style="width:100%;"><img src="/Content/icons/ajax-loader-orange-med.gif" /></span>'
    },
    "searching": false
});
```

console.log in "success" gives me the following json array but it is not bound to the datatable

> [{reference_id: '873', name: 'MapTest', details: 'Sourced from Open Street Maps', num_points: 0, num_sections: 23},
> {reference_id: '899', name: 'Albury C roads', details: 'Sourced from Open Street Maps', num_points: 0, num_sections: 0}]

but it is not bound to the table what am I missing?

**Update**

By removing the success and error properties, data started binding..Why?

```
networkslisttab = $('#networkslisttable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": networkstoolboxURL,
        "dataSrc": ''
        
    }             
    "columns": [
        {
            "data": 'reference_id',
            "width": '15%',
        },
        { "data": 'name' },
        {
            "data": 'num_points',
            "width": '15%',
        },
        {
            "data": 'num_sections',
            "width": '15%',
        }
        
    ],
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "processing": true,
    "autoWidth": false, // need this to handle rendering issues in bootstrap and during re-size.  Note handlers at end of page.
    "scrollY": "200px",  // make it a small scrolling table
    "scrollX": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "language": {
        "processing": '<span style="width:100%;"><img src="/Content/icons/ajax-loader-orange-med.gif" /></span>'
    },
    "searching": false
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, you should not override the jQuery Ajax `success` option in your DataTables `ajax` option.

As documented [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc):

> *...the `success` option of [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) should not be altered - DataTables uses it internally to execute the table draw when the data load is complete.*

Use the `dataSrc` option instead, for any custom processing you may want to do after receiving the JSON response via Ajax.

---

(I have not experimented with the `error` property of the DataTables `ajax` option - it may be the same situation as the `success` option. It's not mentioned in the documentation I linked to.)

Comment: Gotcha!! The success and error properties were not there initially, but i was getting "uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'error')" to fix that i introduced these two without knowing it will introduce another bug :)